# Docker compose permission denied on attached storage in Ubuntu Server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, fstab

Running docker on Ubuntu Server 23.04 with 2 NVMEs. All my compose projects are on the second SSD. Running `docker compose up -d` results in the following:

```
USER@DEVICE:~/docker/authentik$ docker compose up -d
open /home/USER/docker/authentik/docker-compose.yml: permission denied
```

The 2nd NVME was mounted the following way:

```
sudo blkid (To get UUID of the device to add to fstab)
sudo mkdir /mnt/volume
sudo mount -a
systemctl daemon-reload
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/volume/
```

fstab

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_OF_DEVICE /mnt/volume auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=volume 0 0
```

I'm able to run `docker` and `docker compose` without sudo on the primary SSD without issues.

I've tried the following commands to give the docker group permissions on the docker folder inside `/mnt/volume/docker`

```
sudo chgrp -R docker /mnt/volume/docker/
sudo chmod 0755 /mnt/volume/docker/
```

Running `ls -la /mnt/volume/docker`

```
total 4460
drwxr-xr-x 17 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 03:24 .
drwxrwx---  4 yucked yucked    4096 Jul  7 02:52 ..
-rwxrwxr--  1 yucked docker 4487856 May 20 23:29 
drwxrwx---  4 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 02:56 
drwxrwx---  5 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 02:56 
drwxrwxr-x  2 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 03:12 
drwxrwxr-x  6 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 03:13 
drwxrwx---  5 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 02:58 
drwxrwxr-x  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 03:13 
drwxrwx---  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 02:59 
-rwxrwxr--  1 yucked docker     580 May 23 01:04 
drwxrwxr-x  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 03:13 
drwxrwxr-x  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 03:13 
drwxrwxr-x  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  9 00:29 
drwxrwx---  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 02:56 
drwxrwx---  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  9 00:17 
drwxrwx---  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 02:56 
drwxrwxr-x  3 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 03:13 
drwxrwxr-x  4 yucked docker    4096 Jul  7 03:13 
-rwxrwxr--  1 yucked docker     439 Apr 27 23:30
```

Any idea what could be causing this?